# Script to toggle laptop track pad

Tags: shell-script, xinput

I have a script that disables the touchpad on my thinkpad:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

xinput --disable 12
```

How could I adjust the script so that instead of just disabling, it will check the current state of the touchpad and toggle the enable/disable?

Comment: xinput list shows a list all available and attached input devices on your system.Your current device should have id=12 section in its description.You may first show the STATE section then use an case statement to toggle between enable(state 0) disabled (state 1)  URL for reference https://askubuntu.com/questions/65951/how-to-disable-the-touchpad

Answer (score 1):

It's strange that `xinput` can't filter its output itself. But we have `grep`!

`xinput --list-props 12 | grep -q 'Device Enabled.*1$' && echo enabled || echo disabled`

Answer (score 0):

to **toggle** the touchpad you could run a perl one-liner from this script:

```
perl -e '$dev="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"; `xinput list-props $dev` =~ /^.*Device Enabled.+?(\d)$/m ;  $1 ? `xinput --disable $dev` : `xinput --enable $dev`;
```

short expanation:

- the backticks execute a system/linux-command
- while matching the line where it says "Device Enabled" the regex looks for the last numeric character on that line (which is 0 ... for off, or 1 ... for on)
- the /m in the regex means: use each line from the output of the command as a seperate element (otherwise ^ and $ of the regex would mean the beginnen/end of the string, not the line
- the parantheses save the matched number into the Variable $1
- the rest is the ternary operaton: "if true" ? "do this" : "else to this", meaning if $1 equals 0 or 1 -> disable or enable

(to use this in, e.g. "i3" window manager: you would have to write:

```
bindsym XF86TouchpadToggle exec --no-startup-id perl -e '{`xinput list-props 10` =~ /^.*Device Enabled.+?(\d)$/m and  {$1 ? `xinput --disable 10` : `xinput --enable 10`}} '
```